# Kotlin Type Parameters with Upper Bounds

Tags: generics, kotlin

I expect the following to produce a compilation error, but it doesn't. Any ideas why?

```
fun <T, U: T> foo(a: T, b: U) {
    println("$a $b")
}

foo("bar", 123)
```

If I call `foo()` with explicit type arguments, it fails to compile as expected:

```
foo<String, Int>("bar", 123)
Error: Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'String'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler tries quite hard to fit the parameters you've provided to a function signature. In this case, it infers the type parameters to be `Any` and `Int`, so it basically calls the function like this, which of course satisfies the upper bound requirement, because `Any` is a supertype of `Int`:

```
foo<Any, Int>("bar", 123)
```

You can check that this is indeed what's happening in at least two different ways.

1. You can open intention actions (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>⌥↩</kbd> on macOS) when your cursor is on the `foo` function call and choose `Add explicit type arguments`. This will produce the line above.
2. You can make the function [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) and print the type parameters' classes - these will be the parameters that it knows about at compile time.

   ```
   inline fun <reified T, reified U: T> foo(a: T, b: U) {
       println("$a $b")
       println(T::class) // class kotlin.Any
       println(U::class) // class kotlin.Int
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The type inference tries to find a suitable pair. In this case it would be the explicit

```
foo<Any, Int>("bar", 123)
```

The compiler knows the relation of `T` and `U` and thus just needs to find the common super type for `String` and `Int` for `T`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the compiler has no idea what type you mean by `T`, so it has to guess, and it doesn't necessarily guess the *strictest* type. One assumption of languages that use type inference is that the programmer meant something correct. [`String` and `Int` are both descendants of type `Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html), so the compiler can resolve the first call by substituting `Any` in place of `T`. Hence, there is no error.

Once you specifically specify types, the compiler has a better idea of what you want, and in that case it is an error. But the first case is correct.